# Unable to add data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsxEG.jpg)

I am trying to add data from firebase firestore to my recycler views which are placed in one main recycler view. So first I am trying to add data in sub recycler views one by one but when I am trying to set layoutmanager on my recycler views it is giving me null object reference error. And in first recycler view it is not giving any error but it is not adding any data. Can someone please help me out. It is okay even if you tell or share video how to add data in different recycler views.

Comment: Please add some relevant code to your question to make it more understandable and reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from firestore happens async. This means that populating your recyclerview occurs before the data is fetched( it does not wait for you to get data from firestore)
What you could do is to use a callback function or to populate your recyclerview in the onCompleteListener.
Example:

```
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    //populate recyclerview here     
                } else {
                  //error
                }
            });
```

Read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)